# Requesting a variable from html to node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am currently using express to submit my form. In my html, I have a 20 inputs with different ids. The ids for the inputs are address1,address2,address3... I am calling the variables from node js by using req.body.address1. The client has the option of either filling out all 20 inputs or only one or etc. I want to see outputs in my console using node js. Is there any way I can do this without typing `console.log(req.body.address)` for each variable. Is there a way you can say `req.body.address of a count`? Please comment if any confusions occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `address[]` as variable name in HTML. So `req.body.address` will be array and one `console.log` will be require.

Or use some js-magic

```
console.log(Object.keys(req.body).reduce(function(r, k) {if (k.indexOf('address') == 0) r[k] = req.body[k]; return r; }, {}))
```

`Object.keys` returns all key from body, then `reduce` walk by them and put `req.body[k]` with key `k` who started from "address" (check by `.indexOf('address') == 0`) to result object.